# How do we detect and change styles at runtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, vcl-styles

It's cool that Delphi XE3 and below have styles for our applications. But I've noticed that we can mark as many styles as we want and them choose which of them to use as default.

It means that we could change styles at will, but how to do it in code? And how to let the user choose which style to use in our software?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`TStyleManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager) does what you need to accomplish this task. Use [`TStyleManager.StyleNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.StyleNames) to get a list of the styles, and [`TStyleManager.TrySetStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.TrySetStyle) to change them at runtime.

To see how this works, start a new `VCL Forms Application`. Add all of the VCL styles you want to the project, and drop a `TComboBox` on a form. You'll need to add the `implementation` `uses` clause like I have below:

```
uses
  Vcl.Themes;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: String;
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
    for s in TStyleManager.StyleNames do
       ComboBox1.Items.Add(s);
    ComboBox1.Sorted := True;
    // Select the style that's currently in use in the combobox
    ComboBox1.ItemIndex := ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf(TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.Name);
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How do you know so much?

Comment: I read the VCL source code, the documentation that's available, lots of StackOverflow posts (even ones I know nothing about that just look interesting), and write lots of code to try to figure out different things. :-)

Comment: @EASI Very often we don't know the answer and just do a web search to find out. That's how I located the dupe of this question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. After using `TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]);` Modal window become non Modal? DX10.